# Add active state to navigation in links as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm unsure how possible this is, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

I have a simple scroll through site, each with separate sections as you scroll — clearly defined by colours. I have some fixed navigation on the right, which when clicked on a link, it smooth scrolls down (or up) to that section. This is all working fine.

What I'm after is for the link colour in the navigation to change as you scroll into that section — marking it as the 'active' section. I thought I could do a simple 'addClass' or 'css' jQuery if clicked, it changes, but there's also the ability for users to scroll freely so it would be good if the navigation links changed as the user scrolls to determine which section you are in.

http://dataveyes.com/en/ — how this website works, but the nav links change colour depending on what section you are on as you scroll.

I won't post any HTML just yet, as I want to know if something like this is possible.

UPDATE

HTML for navigation

```
<div class="menu-navigation-desktop not-mobile">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item-home"><a class="smooth-scroll-no-offset" href="#home"><span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">home</span></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-we"><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#we">We</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-design"><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#design">Design</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-sustainability"><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#sustainability">Sustainability</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-form"><a class="contact-form-action"><span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">compose</span></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-contact"><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#contact"><span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">phone</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds as though you're after something like jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

Comment: Hmm, I think, essentially, I need to use jQuery to calculate the height of each section, then as you scroll, once the nav reaches the calculated height max, it changes to suit the new section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
var sections = $('.section');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    sections.removeClass('selected').each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top,
            bottom = top + $(this).height();
        if (currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/1/

Comment: Thanks for this — I think this is pretty much it. The only thing is the class, for example, needs to be applied to a list of navigation links, rather than the actual slide. Any thoughts?

Comment: do the links have a corresponding href for the section id?

Comment: Updated my navigation with the HTML — yes, they have hrefs :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Pete. It's nearly there. With the line where it adds the class to the href, I also need it to add the class to the '.menu-navigation-desktop ul li' which is the parent of the a href that has the class added. So, can it also add the 'active-slide' class to the parent li?

`<li class="menu-item-we"><a class="smooth-scroll active-slide" href="#we">We</a></li>

Comment: @rdck I have an updated version that uses the percentage of div available to highlight the section - seems to work a bi better than the last version - http://jsfiddle.net/ebnLE/6/